# would it be straight forward to implement a spatial transformer network in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

i am interested in trying things out with a spatial transformer network and I can't find any implementation of it in caffe or tensorflow, which are the only two libraries I'm interested in using.  I have a pretty good grasp of tensorflow but was wondering if it would be straight forward to implement with the existing building blocks that tensorflow offers without having to do something too complicated like write a custom c++ module

Comment: what math operations do you do in a spatial transformer network ?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is very straight forward to setup the Tensorflow graph for a spatial transformer network with the existing API.

You can find an example implementation in Tensorflow here [1].

[1] https://github.com/daviddao/spatial-transformer-tensorflow

Answer (score 1):

There is an implementation in caffe here. https://github.com/daerduoCarey/SpatialTransformerLayer

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow has a implementation of Spatial Transformer Network in the models repository - https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/transformer